# Wiring models to each other with navigation properties without using Find in controller .NET MVC

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, model, controller, navigation

I want to know whether .NET MVC is supposed to wire up models simply through model definition. So, if we have two model classes Company and Employee...

```
public Company{
     [Key]
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string someVariable {get; set;}

     [ForeignKey("ID")]
     public virtual IEnumerable<Employee> Employees {get; set;}
}

public Employee{
     [Key]
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string whateverVariable {get; set;}
     public int CompanyID {get; set;}

     [ForeignKey("CompanyID")]
     public virtual Company Company {get; set;}
}
```

if, in the controller, i do...

```
Company cModel = db.Company .Find(id)
```

should the navigation property Employees be automatically filled in with the employees of that company based on the CompanyID because of the association. Or, do I still have to do this...

```
cModel.Employee = db.Employee.Find(id);
```

I can't get the automatic wiring to work so I want to know whether it should work and there something wrong with how I'm wiring it or I should just wire it up using the Find method in controller. Using the Find method works, but, it's a bit slow that's why I'm looking for a faster method.

Comment: This wouldn't be a function of MVC, it would be a function of something like Entity Framework.  If the navigation properties are set up *there* and configured to load automatically, it should work without having to manually populate the properties.  (Which is ideal, since the logic to do that should be closer to the model than the controller.)  The only real distinction should be whether navigation properties eager-load or lazy-load.  This may get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I am using EF, however, I have the contingency to have models extracted from the database, but, not to have anything changing the database. I'm using EF to generate code-first database models and not the Entity Framework designer using xml wiring. Do I need the EF designer to take advantage of this EF wiring? In any case, I'm taking a look at the link. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I have verified this is supposed to work. I needed to play around with Fluent API, foreign keys etc. You shouldn't have to make any explicit database calls.

Now that it works it is quite a bit faster, however, not as fast as using sql queries directly. My page is pretty heavy, so, this might have something to do it. I need to further make sure I'm not making any unnecessary database calls.